# How to handle forgot password/ reset password through link

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify, forgot-password, reset-password

How to relay(fetch and auto submit) the code from email into our app upon launching it? Im using react native aws-amplify default `forgotPasswordSubmit` function.

`Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)`

Answer (score 0):

docs state this:

```
    import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

// Send confirmation code to user's email (this sends the email, and consolelogs what is sent)
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Collect confirmation code and new password, then (this lets you reset the password)
Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

To have it so that it automatically goes from the email to the link would require you to do something with the "email template"

specifically, you can make it so that the template send you to a website page with a :slug for the URL that is passed into the "conformation code area" and useEffect could reload the page after this, to submit the information.

though I have not used anything AWS before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the deep linking in android.manifest file. Guess the link is working but it not navigating to the screen i want. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app it is giving me this error. and also How do i obtain the code at the end of the link

Comment: That can also happen if your function component is not spelt with a capital letter.

Comment: That error almost always means you are either "breaking the rules of hooks" or for some reason, you are not using a capital letter for the name of your function component.

Comment: you will need to post your whole code. most likely you are placing your hooks in the wrong section. codevolution on youtube has very specific and easy videos on hooks

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.  This is my code`const resetLinking = {
     prefixes: ['password://forgot'],
     config: {
         screens: {
            ResetPassword:{
                path: 'ResetPassword',
                // parse: {
                //     code: (code) => `${code}`
                // }
             }
         }
     }
 }`. I will check out codevolution for sure Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this doc for more information:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#forgot-password

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you already started the password recovery process with

```
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
```

so, you already know the username, and the user probably has received an email with a verification code.

You can't just "fetch" data from an email into your app. The only thing you can do is, creating a link in the email, which, when clicked opens your app. This link will for instance look like `https://yourapp.com/recovery?code=12345656` This is called ["Deep Linking"](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)

This will allow you to extract the verification code from the clicked link. Now, you will have to ask the user for a new password. Once you have all necessary information (ie the preentered username, the verification code and the new password) available, you can finally call

```
Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
```

I won't provide any code here, as I don't see much sense in copying the docs or some tutorial. Have a look at the docs or one of the many tutorials out there. If you then have specific problems with your code, feel free to update your question with the details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the deep linking in android.manifest file. Guess the link is working but it not navigating to the screen i want. ```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app``` it is giving me this error. and also How do i obtain the code at the end of the link